# Как правильно сгенерировать name для form?

Tags: php

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
      $content = "
      <form class='item-card' name='$randomString' action='reload.php' method = 'post' enctype = 'multipart/form-data'>
    </form>";
```

Пробую рандомно создать name для form, но почему то не передает сгенерированное значение в атрибут, в чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, нужно сохранить в переменную результат работы функции:

```
$randomString = generateRandomString();
$content = "<form class='item-card' name='$randomString' action='reload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'></form>";
```